# posting drop down values to mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

can someone please show me how i would post select drop down values along side my text input values into mysql database.

I have the following and am not sure how dropdown values should be handled.

Thanks

```
<form action=\"includes/welcomestats.php\" method=\"post\" id=\"form1\">            

    <input type=\"text\" name=\"location\" id=\"location\" maxlength=\"30\" placeholder=\"Location: e.g. London\">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter Your Location</label><br/>
    <br/>

    <input type=\"text\" name=\"local_station\" id=\"local_station\" maxlength=\"30\" placeholder=\"Local Train Station\"><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter a Local Train Station</label><br/><br/><br/>

    <h5>About You</h5><br/>
    <select name=\"formGender\" style=\"min-width:125px;\">
      <option value=\"\">Select...</option>
      <option value=\"M\">Male</option>
      <option value=\"T\">Female</option>
    </select>
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter Your Gender</label>
    <br/><br/>

    <input type=\"submit\" class=\"welcome-submit2\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Next ->\" id=\"submit\"/>
    </form>


    <?php
    require_once("session.php"); 
    require_once("functions.php");
    require('_config/connection.php');
    ?>
    <?php 
    session_start();
    include '_config/connection.php'; 
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT location FROM ptb_profiles WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");
    if(!$result) 
    { 
    echo "The username you entered does not exist"; 
    } 
    else 
    if($location!= mysql_result($result, 0)) 
    { 
    echo ""; 
        $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_profiles SET location ='".addslashes($display_name)."' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id'].""); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Select field values are handled same way as any other field. So if you have select field like  -

```
    <select name=\"formGender\" style=\"min-width:125px;\">
      <option value=\"\">Select...</option>
      <option value=\"M\">Male</option>
      <option value=\"T\">Female</option>
    </select>
```

You can use

```
      $gender = $_POST['formGender']
```

**Update**
That will give you either M or F.

Comment: It will give you M or F, not Male or Female